# making a custom directive for input-field of custom type to be added in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to design a custom directive which will return me different input fields for different input types like  text, number , datepicker, etc.

Currently I am using this to accompolish this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12" ng-repeat="option in parameterList">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
        <input type="{{option.inputType}}" 
               class="form-control" 
               name="name" 
               placeholder="Enter the value" 
               ng-model="inputs[$index]" 
               ng-disabled="isNull[$index]">
    </div>
</div>
```

But I want to use a custom angular directive which can return input-fields such that they can be used in the html page.

I am new to making directives in angularJS so please explain. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: read by your self it's very easy /

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a specific programming question. You just need to read some tutorials on directives, and StackOverflow is not a tutorial site.

Official docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Tutorials: https://www.google.com/search?q=angularjs+directive+tutorial

Answer (score 0):

**your template -- temp.html**

```
<div class="col-xs-12" ng-repeat="option in parameterList">


    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
        <input type="{{option.inputType}}" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Enter the value" ng-model="inputs[$index]" ng-disabled="isNull[$index]">

    </div>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('docsIsolateScopeDirective', [])
    .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.parameterList= {};
}])
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      parameterList: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'temp.html'
  };
});
```

**use as**

```
<div parameter-list='parameterList'></div>
```

Comment: i will need a datepicker too if it is a date. If it is Possible

Comment: is it possible to set the type of input field inside the directive only. So that I can even make structured input types.